# Multiline text using handlebars and avoiding script injection

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a textarea on my webpage where the user can type anything he wants, including newlines. Later I use this text in a table. Since this text is multiline it should be shown as multiline too. The only solutions I saw so far to actually convert "normal" text to html formatted multiline involves regexes whereby `\r\n` is replaced by `<br/>` tags.

This works, but that means that in handlebars I need to substitute my text using `{{{myVariable}}}`, otherwise it will just print out `<br/>` statements in text instead of using html tags.

The problem however is that I am showing user input data. If I just go and directly copy paste user text using `{{{}}}` the user could perfectly type html, js,... statements and they would all get parsed/executed by the webbrowser (even a simple `<i>` or `<b>` would be shown as italic or bold).

So the question is: How do I insert multiline text using handlebars without exposing my website to script injection?

Comment: `white-space:pre-wrap` ?

Comment: the `pre` tag removes all formatting (CSS)

Comment: huh? i'm saying that you can show multi-line text in a div, straight from a textarea.value, if the white-space style property is set to pre, pre-wrap or pre-line. that way, you don't need <br> tags and you keep the lines from the textarea.

Comment: also, is the input shown to other users or just the user who typed? if it's only shown to the user who typed it, there's no need to worry about what they type; XSS is a lot easier using devtools...